# Добавить css стили только для первого уровня вложенности

Tags: css

Есть блок

```
<div class="nav-links">
  <a href="/test">First link 1 level</a>
  <div class="sub-block">
    <a href="/test2">First link 2 level</a>
    <a href="/test2">Second link 2 level</a>
  </div>
  <a href="/test">Second link 1 level</a>
  <a href="/test">Third link 1 level</a>
</div>
```

Как создать стили для ссылок первого уровня, чтобы они НЕ передались на ссылки второго уровня?
Классов на ссылках нет. Можно обращаться только через тег.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ```.nav-links > a {
  color: #f00;
}```

Comment: Отдельно в codepan так действительно работало. Но, в моём проекте (Angular, scss) пишет "inherited from a.link.dropdown". Добавил скрин в вопрос.

Comment: добавь пример результата, который ты хочешь увидеть. К каким конкретно элементам должны применяться стили в твоем примере

Comment: Ваш результат полностью правильный. Код в codepan отработал правильно. Не понятно почему этот код не работает в моём приложении. Там эти стили распространяются и на ссылки первого уровня и на ссылки вложенные в div sub-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так что ли ?

```css
a{
display: block;
}
a:not(.sub-block > a){
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-links">
  <a href="/test">First link 1 level</a>
  <div class="sub-block">
    <a href="/test2">First link 2 level</a>
    <a href="/test2">Second link 2 level</a>
  </div>
  <a href="/test">Second link 1 level</a>
  <a href="/test">Third link 1 level</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Отдельно в codepan так действительно работало. Но, в моём проекте (Angular, scss) пишет "inherited from a.link.dropdown". Добавил скрин в вопрос.